# how to append/insert a child based on the path value extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

```
Ext.getCmp('treepanel-id').getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].getPath('parent')
```

i am getting :

```
"//Grandparent/Parent1/leaf1"
```

i need to insert a leaf after the path
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to do this, but, from your question I see that you want to append a sibling node after the current selected node. As you already have a reference to the selected node, you can achieve this like so:

```
var selectedNode = Ext.getCmp('treepanel-id').getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0],
    parentOfSelectedNode = selectedNode.parentNode,
    selectedNodeIndex = parentOfSelectedNode.indexOf(selectedNode);

parentOfSelectedNode.insertChild(selectedNodeIndex + 1, {
    text: 'New sibling node',
    leaf: true
});
```